# How to create a graph in excel from data table in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, graph, epplus

I am using `EPPLUS` version(v4.0.30319) , and i have data in datatable as shown below.But i am getting error in below code for `LoadFromCollection`

```
  private static void DrawGraph()
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        ExcelPackage pckGraph = null;
        string path = @"D:\PTP\graph\ptpgraph.xlsx";
        try
        {
            dt = CreateDatatable();
            var file_Summary = new FileInfo(path);
            if (File.Exists(path))
                File.Delete(path);
            using (pckGraph = new ExcelPackage(file_Summary))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet wsSummary = pckGraph.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PTPGraph");
                ExcelChart chart = wsSummary.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.ColumnClustered);
               // chart.XAxis.Title.Text = "Months"; //give label to x-axis of chart  
                chart.XAxis.Title.Font.Size = 10;
               // chart.YAxis.Title.Text = "Usage(kwh)"; //give label to Y-axis of chart  
                chart.YAxis.Title.Font.Size = 10;
                chart.SetSize(1200, 300);
                chart.SetPosition(1, 0, 5, 0);//loadLoadFromCollection(dt, false, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1); 
                wsSummary.Cells.LoadFromCollection(dt.AsEnumerable());
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Month";
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Current Year Consumption";
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Previous Year Consumption";
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //wsSummary.Cells[1, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //var row = 1;
                //var consumptionCurrentYearSeries = chart.Series.Add(("B" + (row + 1) + ":" + "B" + (dt.AsEnumerable().Count() + 1)), ("A" + (row + 1) + ":" + "A" + (dt.AsEnumerable().Count() + 1)));
                //consumptionCurrentYearSeries.Header = "Current Year";
                //var consumptionPreviousYearSeries = chart.Series.Add(("C" + (row + 1) + ":" + "C" + (dt.AsEnumerable().Count() + 1)), ("A" + (row + 1) + ":" + "A" + (dt.AsEnumerable().Count() + 1)));
                //consumptionPreviousYearSeries.Header = "Previous Year";
                pckGraph.Save(); //this statement will save created excel to the passed file path  
                pckGraph.Dispose(); //will dispose the package  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
 private static DataTable CreateDatatable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Field",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Differences", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote Tx Frequency","412" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Hub Tx Frequency", "388" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote Modulation", "622" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote ChannelBW", "383" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote TxPower", "725" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Hub TxPower", "681" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote Ant Polarisation", "407" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote Equipment Type", "449" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Remote Equipment Vendor", "369" });
            return dt;
        }
```

My requirement is need to generate a graph as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this package, but this is how you need to declare

```
wsSummary.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromCollection(dt.AsEnumerable());
```

to make it readability for `LoadFromCollection`

Comment: Now LoadFromCollection throwing {"Parameter count mismatch."} error,i have edited my question program